# Run a method every time a try catch is used in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, try-catch

I was wondering if it's possible to write code that runs everytime a try catch block is used in ASP.NET without having to add any attribute to the method or code inside a try catch block. 
By that I mean one piece of code for all of the try catches in an entire project. 
Would it be possible to customize try catch or to invoke a method everytime a try catch is used? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I know you want to do that, but chances are you are really looking for a way to globally handle errors, you should research global error handling

Comment: @johnny5 is right. What you need is likely an action filter similar to `HandleErrorAttribute`. You might even want to derive from that. You can then apply this globally using your FilterConfig.cs.

Comment: @devKoen1 what are you trying to do? Elmah and Glimpse already capture error information. Adding them to the project adds the appropriate hooks. APM libraries like Application Insights work in the same way. All of these allow you to log/send specific messages programmatically.

Comment: You are right @Panagiotis Kanavos. But it would be nice not having to add code for elmah error logging in every catch block but in one global piece of code instead

Comment: The global exception handlers work if no local handler has handled the exception. You still haven't explained what you want to do. Most likely, there is a solution already available. For example, [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) allows you to specify retries, timeouts etc. as policies.

Comment: ELMAH and all logging frameworks also allow you to log exceptions with a single line. Most logging frameworks accept an exception as parameter. ELMAH allows you to log an exception through [Error Signaling](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx) with `ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext.Raise(exc);`

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos, that pretty much answers my question. There's no customizing try catch but global exceptions are a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is finally:

```
try {}
catch(Exception ex)
{}
finally {
//Code executes after try catch regardless of outcome
}
```

What you're really looking for:

```
   public class GlobalExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
    {
        public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
        {
            //elmah logging code for context.exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but what I mean is one piece of code in an entire project for every try catch in the project. I'll make the question more specific.

Comment: @devKoen1 No problem, are you asking in theory if it's possible or are you trying to solve a problem?

Comment: @RandomUs1r global exception handlers are available in *all* platforms. WInforms, WPF, Webforms, MVC.

Comment: To solve a certain problem. The thing is, we want to apply elmah error log for every catch and I'm hoping there is a shorter solution than adding code to every catch.

Comment: @devKoen1 If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is a global exception logger, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own try-catch, like the following:

```
public static class Try
{
    public static void Action(Action a)
    {
        try
        {
            a();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //do whatever you want here
            throw new OtherException(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And use it everywhere in your project:

```
Try.Action(() => 
// code to be wrapped with try
));
```

Comment: This will not work,  the way it is is currently you cannot specify the internal of your catch block you need another action